# Java Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

I am trying to design an application where I will have a Map of `IAction` objects.  Each `IAction` object has a method `IAction IAction.processAction()` where it is executing the knowledge contained within it.  This could querying the database calling a web service, etc.   After the execution of each `IAction` control is then sent to the next `IAction` instance.

When the application starts up it will contain a Map of `Map` that will be in the correct order of execution.  The key of `Integer` type of the `Map` is the order for which execution will run.  `IAction.processAction()` could jump control to the last `IAction` in the Map or stop it all together.

I can visualize the code in my head and I've written some lines to help me with this.  I am looking for a Design Pattern that would easily help with this type of processing.  I am not sure if the Command pattern would fit this role.

I was hoping someone could tell me which patterns they feel may fit the bill or not.

Comment: How come you never accepted any answer to your questions? Did you only receive bad answers?

Comment: a) java doesn't really use "I"s in fornt of interfaces b) homework question? c) be careful trying to fit a pattern to your problem; you could end up with and anti-pattern

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the Command pattern certainly has some relevance here.

However, I think you're going about it the wrong way.  Design patterns are essentially meant to be examples and recipes to steer your thoughts along productive lines when designing how a product's going to work.  What you're doing, taking a good design and then trying to shoehorn it into an "official" Design Pattern, is all backwards.

Other than that, what's the key in your map of `IAction` objects?  It sounds like a (possibly linked) list is a much more natural structure for them.

Comment: I haven't done testing on it, but wouldn't a LinkedList be a bad choice for something that may seek to the end of the list from any point? ("`IAction.processAction()` could jump control to the last `IAction`")

Comment: @ R. Bemrose: in that case yes, definitely.  My understanding was that the actions were tried in sequence: "After the execution of each `IAction`, control is then sent to the next `IAction` instance."  The actual data structure does depend on how things fit together, though, which is why this was a suggestion for consideration rather than a recommendation.

Comment: You could be right about trying to shoe-horn a design pattern.  I have a Map of IAction when a message comes in based on definitions in my database.  The first IAction to be processed is also defined in the tables.  The sequence of all of the following IAction could change at runtime.  I am trying to define the best interface and controller that acts on those interfaces.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a variation of the [Chain of Responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Your IAction clearly follows the **Command** pattern.

Your list of actions to be executed could be a **Composite** Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code will help us to provide good solutions. Without the code, you will get guidelines only.

And one more thing : ***Design patterns are just guidelines***. While implementing a solution, you should not thing your solution in a particular design pattern. After coming up with solution to your problem, then you can decide if your solution fits into a particular pattern. If not, still you can implement your solution without any design pattern.

[Command_Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) `seems to be the solution for executing simple commands`. If your commands are independent of each other, simple command pattern solves your problem. If some of your commands are dependent other commands, then you have to use [Chain-of-responsibility_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) by establishing hierarchy.

[Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern can be used to store all your commands in Map object.